# Create a Promise from an API (object)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The API I'm using is `owapi.net/api/v3/u/Calvin-1337/stats` (the name will change). Let's say I wanted the `tier`, that'd be `JSON.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.tier` and I can parse that and get it okay. But now I want to create a promise. Let's make it for the `overall_stats` so... `us.stats.competitive.overall_stats` and I only want values from there for the moment. I wan't to be able to do something like:

```
const core = require("myNodePackage");

core.getCompOverallStats("Calvin-1337").then(data > {
    console.log(data.tier) // grandmaster
    // etc through to
    console.log(data.prestige) // 5
});
```

This is totally wrong but what I had thought about:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch"); // used to get json data

getCompOverallStats = (playerName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // only want this for us.stats.competitive.overall_stats

        fetch("https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Calvin-1337/stats")
            .then(function(res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(json) {
                //console.log(json.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.tier) => grandmaster
            });
```

Comment: using "q" module.

Comment: return fetch.then(d=>d.json()); is enough...

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getCompOverallStats = (playerName) =>
  // grab the player stats
  fetch(`https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/${playerName}/stats`)
    // parse json
    .then(res => res.json())
    // pull out the one object you want
    .then(data => data.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats);
```

That should be enough.

You should now be able to call

`getCompOverallStats('some-pl4y3r').then(overall => console.log(overall.tier));`

Comment: With this I'm getting an error.
`core.getCompOverallStats("Calvin-1337").then(data => {
                                                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Ignore this, I forgot to return it. Thank you.